# Why can't Vite recognize the src folder?

Tags: typescript, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit project in which I use Socket.IO for WebSocket communication.

For that I need to run the function that inits the WebSocket server from the vite.config.ts file in a plugin.

My vite.config.ts file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import type http from 'http';
import initSocketIoServer from './src/lib/server/socketIoServer';
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        sveltekit(),
        {
            name: 'vite-plugin-socket-io',
            configureServer(server) {
                initSocketIoServer(server.httpServer as http.Server);
            },
        },
    ],
});
```

I don't have any errors in the file, but when I try to run `npm run dev`

I get:

```
failed to load config from C:\vs_code_projects\TypeScript\ej_coop\vite.config.ts
error when starting dev server:
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'src' imported from C:\vs_code_projects\TypeScript\ej_coop\vite.config.ts.timestamp-1692059596974-1e8475088e131.mjs
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)  
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:951:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1000:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1214:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:165:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:844:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:431:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36)
```

I tried restarting the editor, import in different ways, even turning my PC off and on. Nothing works.

And the weirdest thing is that it worked before, and I don't recall changing that file, or any other config files for that matter.

Edit: So apparently, the bug refers to the first instance where I import from src like this: import x from 'src/...'

but I've added an alias in svelte.config.js vite.config.ts and .svelte-kit/tsconfig.json:

[svelte.config.js]

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        // adapter-auto only supports some environments, see https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-auto for a list.
        // If your environment is not supported or you settled on a specific environment, switch out the adapter.
        // See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters for more information about adapters.
        adapter: adapter(),


        alias: {
            src: 'src'
        },
    },
};

export default config;
```

[svelte-kit/tsconfig.json]

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
            "src": [
                "../src"
            ],
            "src/*": [
                "../src/*"
            ],
            "$lib": [
                "../src/lib"
            ],
            "$lib/*": [
                "../src/lib/*"
            ]
        },
        "rootDirs": [
            "..",
            "./types"
        ],
        "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "preserveValueImports": true,
        "lib": [
            "esnext",
            "DOM",
            "DOM.Iterable"
        ],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "esnext",
        "target": "esnext",
        "ignoreDeprecations": "5.0"
    },
    "include": [
        "ambient.d.ts",
        "./types/**/$types.d.ts",
        "../vite.config.ts",
        "../src/**/*.js",
        "../src/**/*.ts",
        "../src/**/*.svelte",
        "../tests/**/*.js",
        "../tests/**/*.ts",
        "../tests/**/*.svelte"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "../node_modules/**",
        "./[!ambient.d.ts]**",
        "../src/service-worker.js",
        "../src/service-worker.ts",
        "../src/service-worker.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So APPARENTLY, Vite imports have to have a '/' at the start, otherwise, it's considered a package.

So in `vite.config.ts` we have:

```
export default defineConfig({
    ...
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '/@src': './src'
        },
    },
});
```

In `tsconfig.json` (not .svelte-kit/tsconfig.json cause that file is being reset when running the project):

```
{
    "extends": "./.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "paths": {
            "/@src": [
                "./src"
            ],
            "/@src/*": [
                "./src/*"
            ],
        }
    },
}
```

And when importing we write:

```
import ... from "/@src/...";
```

Comment: That should not be the case, otherwise SvelteKit's own aliases would not work at all.

Comment: The problem was probably that you did not specify add the `./` in the value part, i.e. it should have been: `alias: { src: './src' } }`, mapping `src` exactly to `src` does nothing, it is a replacement, so you can also alias module names to other module names.

Comment: I tried it. It did not work. SvelteKit aliases worked for me, but not for code that's being run from vite plugins.

Answer (score 0):

SvelteKit has its own method of defining aliases via the [`kit.alias` option](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#alias) in `svelte.config.js`, which should not require you to touch any other files.

> An object containing zero or more aliases used to replace values in `import` statements. These aliases are automatically passed to Vite and TypeScript.

```js
kit: {
    alias: { src: './src` },
}
```

`.` or `/` at the beginning of the *final value* is required to identify a file path, that is just how Node module resolution works. It does not have to be part of the alias itself.

Comment: SvelteKit aliases did not work for me for code that's being run from Vite plugins

Comment: Well, you can't rely on any Vite features in plugins; Vite has not executed yet. Then again their scope should not be huge; the main point of aliases is to improve the hundreds of imports that make up the *actual* application.